# Crear función propia para calcular longitud

Tags: php, array, php7, php5, undefined

Debo crear una función que calcule la longitud de una cadena de caracteres; por ahora consigo que me devuelva la longitud, pero me muestra el siguiente fallo:

```
Uninitialized string offset
```

Este es el código, y un ejemplo:

```
/**
 * Devuelve la longitud de un texto pasado por parametros.
 */
function longitud($texto){
    $contador=0;
    $final=false;

    //mientras la posicion actual no sea null
    //muestra su contenido e incrementa en uno contador
    while($texto[$contador] != NULL){
        echo $texto[$contador] . "<br/>";
        ++$contador;
    }
    echo $contador;
}
longitud("Hola");
```

Y esto es lo que me muestra en el navegador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo saber cuándo una posición no está definida en una colección en PHP?

Comment: ¿No era suficiente usar [`str_len`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strlen.php)?

Comment: No, el ejercicio es calcular la longitud del texto creando mi propia función. Si uso str_len es trampa!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como bien has determinado, el problema está en la condición de tu bucle `while`. La manera de controlar el acceso a un índice inexistente de un `array` es a través de la función `isset()` ya que esta, además de detectar que no sea `NULL` detecta que esté definida, que es por lo que te salta el *notice*.

```
function longitud($texto){
    $contador=0;
    $final=false;

    while(isset($texto[$contador])) {
        echo $contador;
        echo $texto[$contador] . "<br/>";
        ++$contador;
    }
}

longitud("Hola");
```

Si te das cuenta el *notice* te salta en la linea donde se evalúa la condición del `while` ya que para poder comprobar que el contenido de ese índice no es `NULL` estás referenciando un índice que no existe.

**EDIT**

Al tratarse de un bucle en el que sabemos de antemano el número de iteraciones que se van a realizar (tantas iteraciones como carácteres tenga el `string`) un bucle `while` sería innecesario, en su lugar es más sencillo usar un bucle `for`:

```
function longitud($texto){
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($texto); $i++) {
        echo $texto[$i] . "<br/>";
    }
}

longitud("Hola");
```

Comment: Eso era lo que me faltaba, no sabía que existía una función así, ¡muchas gracias! ¿y cada lenguaje de programación tiene una función parecida a isset()?

Comment: Cada lenguaje tendrá su manera, no veo el por que no. En Javascript, por ejemplo, puedes comprobar que el `typeof` de la variable es distinto a `'undefined'`.

Answer (score 0):

Sólo como aportación, la función podría escribirse de otras maneras:

#### Combinando `count` con  `str_split`:

```
function longitud($s){
    return count(str_split($s));
}
```

---

#### Combinando `array_sum` y `count_chars`

```
function longitud($s){
    return array_sum(count_chars($s));
}
```

En ambos casos la cadena es convertida a un array de caracteres que luego pueden contarse o sumarse.